# Hover to see value on a chart

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet on Google Drive, which until today I was able to see a value when I hovered on the dot with, but now it's not working anymore.

Unfortunately I can't remember if I changed a setting and I don't manage to find any way to fix this.

Can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: I suggest to share a doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows data in advanced edit mode, and in View mode:

[image: View Mode]

Comment: It doesn't work anymore in any mode. I've tried switching modes multiple times.

Comment: very strange, because I created new chart in order to test before posting the answer. Have you tried to create a new chart?

Comment: Yes, I did create it a few times. It might be due to the data ?

Comment: ok, it would be great then if you share the spreadsheet and post link here. Be careful though not to leave any confidential information inside.